# How to set panels visible and invisible?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am wondering how to set the "blocksPanel" and "briquettesPanel" visible or invisible? I would like the "blocksPanel" visible if "8:1 Compressed Blocks" is selected in the drop down list and the "briquettesPanel" visible if "8:1 Compressed Briquettes" is selected in the drop down list.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  //Create horizontal product + other panel
  var productOtherPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('productOtherPanel')
  .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%');

  //Create horizontal Product Panel  
  var productPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('productPanel').setStyleAttribute('position','relative')
  .setStyleAttribute('left','0%').setVisible(true);
  //Create listBox
  var productList = app.createListBox().setName("productList").setId('productList');
  //Add items to listBox
  productList.addItem("8:1 Compressed Blocks");
  productList.addItem("8:1 Compressed Briquettes");

  //Create horizontal Compressed Blocks panel
  var blocksPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('blocksPanel')
  .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%').setVisible(true);
  //Create Compressed Blocks Size List
  var blocksSizeList = app.createListBox().setName('blocksSizeList').setId('blocksSizeList');
  //addItem fills the Compressed Blocks Size List
  blocksSizeList.addItem("5kg");
  blocksSizeList.addItem("20kg");

  //Create horizontal Briquettes panel
  var briquettesPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('briquettesPanel')
  .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%').setVisible(true);
  //Create Briquettes Size List
  var briquettesSizeList = app.createListBox().setName('briquettesSizeList').setId('briquettesSizeList');
  //addItem fills the Briquettes Size List
  briquettesSizeList.addItem("250g");
  briquettesSizeList.addItem("650g");




  app.add(productOtherPanel);
  productOtherPanel.add(productPanel);
  productPanel.add(productList);

  productOtherPanel.add(blocksPanel);
  blocksPanel.add(blocksSizeList);

  productOtherPanel.add(briquettesPanel);
  briquettesPanel.add(briquettesSizeList);


  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a server change handler for the product list.

```
var handler = app.createServerHandler("panelHandler");
productList.addChangeHandler(handler);
```

Then define the panel handler function as follows. The productList is passed into the 'event' parameter of the handler function.

```
function panelHandler(event) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if (event.parameter.productList == "8:1 Compressed Blocks") {
    app.getElementById('blocksPanel').setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('briquettesPanel').setVisible(false);
  }
  else if (event.parameter.productList == "8:1 Compressed Briquettes") {
    app.getElementById('blocksPanel').setVisible(false);
    app.getElementById('briquettesPanel').setVisible(true);
  }
  return app;
}
```

In the beginning, you need to set blocksPanel visible and briquettesPanel invisible to match the initial state of the product list.

Refer to the [Server Handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler?hl=en) docs for more info.